# Using Dictionary to map byte to BitArray

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures, time-complexity, hashtable

I am developing an application that implements Simple Substitution Cypher. Now for speed reasons (and because that was one of the conditions) I need to use BitArray for encryption and decryption. The user will enter "coded" alphabet and I would need to map it in some way so I chose Dictionary since it uses hash table and has O(1) complexity when the user access data. But now I found myself wondering how can I do this when I have "coded" alphabet initialized like this:

```
BitArray codedAlphabet = new BitArray(bytes);
```

This would make me use 2 for loops to achieve my goal. Does anyone have different idea? Hopefully you understood what I am trying to achieve. Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
namespace Harpokrat.EncryptionAlgorithms
{
// Simple substitution cypher algorithm
    public class SimpleSubstitutionStrategy : IEncryptionStrategy
    {
        private string alphabet;  // message to be encrypted
        private string coded;      // this will be the key (input from file or from UI)

        private ArrayList AlphabetBackUp = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList CodedBackUp    = new ArrayList();

        #region Properties
        public string Alphabet
        {
            get
            {
                return this.alphabet;
            }
            set
            {
                this.alphabet = value;
                foreach (char c in this.alphabet.ToCharArray())
                {
                    this.AlphabetBackUp.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }

        public string Coded
        {
            get
            {
                return this.coded;
            }

            set
            {
                this.coded = "yqmnnsgwatkgetwtawuiqwemsg"; //for testing purposes
                foreach (char c in this.coded.ToCharArray())
            {
                this.CodedBackUp.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public string Decrypt(string message)
    {
        message = message.ToLower();
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
        {
            int indexOfSourceChar = CodedBackUp.IndexOf(message[i]);
            if (indexOfSourceChar < 0 || (indexOfSourceChar > alphabet.Length - 1))
            {
                result += "#";
            }
            else
            {
                result += alphabet[indexOfSourceChar].ToString();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public string Encrypt(string message)
    {
        message = message.ToLower();
        string result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
        {
            int indexOfSourceChar = AlphabetBackUp.IndexOf(message[i]);
            if (indexOfSourceChar < 0 || (indexOfSourceChar > coded.Length - 1))
            {
                result += "#";
            }
            else
            {
                result += coded[indexOfSourceChar].ToString();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you need substitution chiper, why use BitArray? It operates on level of single character, so at least on byte level. Please provide some code of how you are actually encrypting.

Comment: Currently I am encrypting on byte level. I wanted to optimize it even more since I have array list for regular and "coded" alphabet. Please find code in edited question.

Comment: Using `Dictionary` is right way to go, but using `BitArray` is not needed, because you don't need to operate on level of single bits. Using it will just complicate your code without any benefit.

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it.

Comment: And while you're at it, I'd highly suggest replacing those `ArrayList`s with `List<T>`s

Comment: Do `alphabet` and `coded` really need to be set independently? Just that it makes initialization of the two `Dictionary<char, char>` maps you'd need to do Encryption and Decryption unnecessarily complex.  At any rate once you have it you should be implement either Encrypt or Decrypt with a single line of code each (using LINQ `Select` etc.).  BTW I do hope this isn't for anything other than an educational project - simple substitution cyphers are called "simple" for a reason!

Comment: @DylanNicholson of course it's educational project I have several algorithms to implement. I would need 2 Dictionary<char, char> wouldn't I? One for mapping regular alphabet 2nd for mapping coded alphabet to regular? Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a single method to set `alphabet` and `coded` at the same time, that internally builds the two dictionaries you'd need to do Encryption and Decryption, and a helper method to do a get-or-return-default ('#' in your case) on them.
That way you can implement a single function that does either Encryption or Decryption depending on the dictionary passed in (which could be implemented in a single line of code if you're comfortable using LINQ).